# Unable to Read CSV File with Apache Commons CSV - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, apache, csv, ebay-api

I'm attempting to access data from CSV file (which I downloaded from EBay's MIP server) using Apache Commons CSV however I'm encountering the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Index for header 'Selected Category ID' is 4 but CSVRecord only has 1 values!
```

I'm not quite sure the cause since the file clearly contains this index. My CSV file looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the following code to access file:

```
CSVParser csvParser = null;

    String selectedCategoryIDFieldName = "Selected Category ID";

    try {
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(CSVFile));
        csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withHeader("SKU", "Locale", "Title", "Channel", selectedCategoryIDFieldName)
                .withIgnoreHeaderCase()
                .withTrim()
                .withSkipHeaderRecord(true));
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (csvParser != null) {
        List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
        for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
            // Accessing values by the names assigned to each column

            try {
                long currentRecordNumber = csvRecord.getRecordNumber();
                String SKU = csvRecord.get("SKU");
                String categoryID = csvRecord.get(selectedCategoryIDFieldName);
                // ^^ this line throws `IllegalArgumentException`


                System.out.println("Current record number: " + currentRecordNumber);
                System.out.println("SKU - >  " + SKU);
                System.out.println("categoyrID -> "  + categoryID);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
```

I searched around SO and the closest question I found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653173/error-parsing-due-to-csv-differences-before-after-saving-java-w-apache-commons) but it is not related to my question as the format is exactly the same before/after I save it (In other words, I don't see anything wrong with the format like in the other users question).

**Update:** I just realized this error surfaces on the second iteration of the `for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords)` loop (the file only contains one record). However, I still don't understand why it is iterating twice if there's only one record in CSV file.. and why does it only surface by category ID and not by SKU column?

Comment: Your code worked for me. Double-check the format of your CSV file. Make sure the columns line up (i.e., the same number of columns in each row). Maybe you have an extra comma somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be some empty spaces in record 2. Open the file in notepad or notepad++.

I am not familiar with apache commons csv so it may  not be the optimum solution

```
for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
   if(csvRecord.size() >= csvParser.getHeaderMap.size()){  <--- add this if condition
```

Comment: yup, you are correct there is an empty tab space at beginning of line two in notepad++ (but in notepad it's just one normal whitespace). How could I fix this issue without needing to manually edit each file I download?

Comment: @Christopher Take a look at CSVRecord#isConsistent

Answer (score 1):

If trailing values of the row are empty, they may be omitted altogether with theirs delimiters causing size of the header to be bigger than size of the row values. This is pretty valid(?) CSV file. To adapt your parser use `isSet()` method:

```
row.isSet(column) ? row.get(column) : EMPTY
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) a go as it handles broken CSV pretty well (including dealing with unexpected spaces here and there) and it's also [3 times faster](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) than commons-csv. It should also make your code cleaner as you don't have to put try/catch blocks everywhere.

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
settings.detectFormatAutomatically();
settings.setHeaders("SKU", "Locale", "Title", "Channel", selectedCategoryIDFieldName);
// settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //use this if the headers are in the input

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<Record> records = parser.parseAllRecords(new File("/path/to/your.csv"));
```

Hope this helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)